# Odoo 7 set field value with a button

Tags: odoo

I added a boolean field to a openerp 7 form
at `on_change` I call my method in order to change `offer` field values on the form 
my method returns:

```
{'value': {'fieldname': 'newfieldvalue'}}
```

I want replace the boolean field with a button, but my method don't work for buttons
that is the right return value for a button in order to change field values on the same form.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function for that button as follows :- let your field be 'checked'

```
   def pass(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
       return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'checked': True})
```

Answer (score 0):

A button on a form always saves the form first (calls write on the model) and then executes the button method.

So, you will need to write a button method that writes the value into the field and then if you return True I think the form is redisplayed.

Have a look at the Calculate Taxes button on the customer or supplier invoice forms for an example.

Comment: @Nebojsa - this will be a little munged by the comment display but... Form XML `<field name="my_field/><button name="do_foo" string="Run" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>` Code `def do_foo(self, cr, uid, ids, context = None):
 wizard = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context = context)
 my_field_value = wizard.my_field`

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. I am new to wizard coding. From your code example does it mean that wizard has its own table?

Comment: Yes it does but make sure you inherit TransientModel, not Model.  It will create a table in the DB but the Odoo vacuum cron task will come along and clean them up for you.  You also don't need to worry about security for TransientModels

Comment: Thanks, Adrian, for the answer!

Comment: @Adrian Merrall : When using onchange decorator, it does not write to database. So is there a way to use similar approach that can be triggered not by a field change, but by a button press? Couldn't be the button behaviour - saving the form when pressed - overloaded?